# how to generate rss feed by filtering?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, rss

I need to generate an rss feed by filtering.The filterd rss feed should be bind with asp:label.I have three labels.one For displaying date,heading and news.how to generate and bind these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is simple.
You can read a rss feed in the form of xml.You just download the content from the url and read as xml format.then you can extract the contents like in xmls.